# XMLDocument.Load(), hexadecimal value 0x17, is an invalid character

Tags: c#, xmldocument

I'm getting following error while loading an xml file using xmlDocument.Load() method:

[image]

I'm getting this error because I've some invalid character 'ETB' in my XML. How can I fix this? This character is a part of binary encoded image data.

```xml
<prompt>
   <![CDATA[<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/something"><Paragraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/something"><InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center">
        <Image Stretch="None" Width="1024" Height="282"><Image.Source><BitmapImage><base64Binary>(Base 64 encoded data containing 'ETB' Text)
   </base64Binary></BitmapImage></Image.Source></Image></InlineUIContainer></Paragraph></FlowDocument>]]>
</prompt>
```

Base 64 Binary data is like this:

> `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...`

This data has an 'ETB' character in it.

Comment: In between what? It's really unclear where the invalid character is coming from...

Comment: @JonSkeet please check [this](http://4gp.tw/b018/1375170208640.txt) file for complete binary data

Comment: That's simply not valid base64 data. As well as that problematic character, it contains non-ASCII characters. We still don't know where the data came from, but it's *not* valid base64.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This character is a part of binary encoded image data.

Then it shouldn't be in an XML document. An XML document is *text* - typically if you want to include arbitrary binary data, you base64-encode it.

This isn't actually a C# problem or a .NET problem - it's simply that your XML document is invalid.

Comment: My XML has images in base64 form. The node is like `<![CDATA[<FlowDocument xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/something"><Paragraph xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/something"><InlineUIContainer BaselineAlignment="Center"><Image Stretch="None" Width="1024" Height="282"><Image.Source><BitmapImage><base64Binary>`

Comment: My xml document has base64 encoded data, still I'm getting that 'ETB' character. Is there any way to fix using C# code, without touching the xml?

Comment: @Jaguar: No. It's invalid XML. That character really shouldn't be in base64-encoded data. Are you sure that's where the problem is? I suggest you look at the document in a hex editor and try to find that byte.

Comment: Yeah I'm sure the error is with that character. The encoded data is inside `CDATA`. I thought that everything inside CDATA would be ignored by xmlDoc.load()?

Comment: @Jaguar: No, it still needs to be valid character data. I'm sure the error is with that character too - but I'm not convinced it's where you think it is. You should edit your question to show exactly where within your document it is.

Comment: Added part of xml containing base 64 binary data

Comment: @JonSkeet I am also facing same issues the XML files contains multiple characters of these types and these are not loading on XMLDocument. any idea how can i load XMl file into XMLDocument in c#